# How to change v-select item-text color

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-select

I have tried different options, but nothing has worked so far.

```
 <td>
     <v-select
     :items="dispatchOptions"
     dense
     v-model="order_row.date"
     @change="updateDate(order_row)">
     </v-select>
 </td>
```

Comment: can you share what you tried or is this it? have you tried changing css?

Comment: It looks like v-select is a component that lists the options. You would change css within the component for the selected item. Please post full code for more assistance.

Comment: i tried color="red" in the v-select component and also <td style="color: red !important">